# How to get the value or array from one component to other component without storing in localstorage in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components one login component and other home component, I want to get the users data from login component to home component without storing in localstorage,is there any way to get it in angular 8. Here is the code below.

### login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  users:any;
  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.users = [{"user1":"abc"},{"user2":"abcd"},{"user3":"abce"},{"user4":"abt"}];
  }
  storeData(){    
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

}
```

### login.component.html

```
<button (click)="storeData()">Go To Home Page</button>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: You could store it in a variable in a service

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the actual use case there are multiple ways to achieve this. Most often people use one of those two:

1.) Create a shared service which supplies functions to store and read the user data.

2.) Have a common parent component that holds the state and passes it as @Input (https://angular.io/api/core/Input) into the child components.

You can find examples and further use cases in the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Edit:
The solution provided by @Berchmans is also correct, but it shares data between components (which I guess are in the same application) using the HTTP Protocol. That is normally not what you want for application internal communication.